# Union of Algebraic sets

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I need an example with proof, that an infinite union of algebraic sets need not be algebraic. (Hint: it’s probably easiest to think about $\Bbb Z\subset \Bbb C$ …)

Answer (score 2):

The hint is basically the answer.  $\Bbb Z\subseteq\Bbb C$.  Single points are algebraic in $\Bbb C$, while $\Bbb Z$ is not.  The proof that $\Bbb Z$ is not algebraic is because polynomials can only have finitely many zeros.  The proof of that fact is not trivial, but you probably can use that fact since Algebra is a pre-req for Algebraic Geometry.

Comment: The basis theorem should probably be mentioned too.

Comment: Sorry, just that $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is a PID is obviously enough here.

Comment: @NoahOlander Yeah good points both.  Since we are in one dimension the PID property is enough for this example.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_r = \{ x^{2} + y^{2} = r^2 \}$ for $r \in (0,1)$ and take $A=\displaystyle\bigcup_{r\in (0,1)} A_r$.

Then $A$ is the punctured open disk, which is not an algebraic set because it is open, not closed, in the Euclidean topology.

Comment: The circles are algebraic in the real affine plane but not when we consider $\mathbb{C}$ as the complex affine line, which I assumed we were doing, but I suppose it's not clear from the question.